# Angular2 Routing issue -loading app again inside router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

[image]

There is some issue with my angular2 routing which I cant figure out, when I take "localhost:3000" on my browser I am getting two apps, again app is loaded inside my router-outlet.Can someone help me resolve this issue?

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
const routes: Routes = [
{
        path: '', component: AppComponent,
        children:[
            { path: 'login',loadChildren: './components/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
            { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './components/password-reset/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordModule'},
            { path: 'app',loadChildren: './components/app-holder/app-holder.module#AppHolderModule' },
        ]
}
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

app.component.html

```
<header></header>
<div class="app-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

app-holder.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppHolderComponent } from './app-holder.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppHolderComponent
    }
];

export const AppHolderRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

login.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const LoginRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

password-reset.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PasswordResetComponent } from './reset-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PasswordResetComponent }
];

export const LoginRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: what is appHolderComponent? post the code

Comment: appholder is just a component you see when you login, nothing inside html as of now. The problem is I can see two headers.

Comment: Just change your default component to login instead of appcomponent,

Comment: Then how will I get header and footer as common in both login and app-holder?

Comment: try this   path: '', component: AppHolderComponent, pathMatch: 'full'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a route with empty path (`''`) and no children, use

```
    path: '', component: AppHolderComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
```

otherwise the router keeps searching for child routes.

Your app is added inside itself because of

```
    path: '', component: AppComponent,
```

`AppComponent` is already added when Angular is bootstrapped, no need to add it again using the router.

**update**

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'login',loadChildren: './components/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
   { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './components/password-reset/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordModule'},
   { path: 'app',loadChildren: './components/app-holder/app-holder.module#AppHolderModule' },
];
```

Comment: If I remove  path: '', component: AppComponent, from app.routing , I get this error --  Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren ;

Comment: I suppose its because login and app-holder module are lazyloaded they have to be children right?

Comment: Your `login`, `reset-password`, and `app` routes need to become root routes. Can you please add the routes as you have them now to your question?

Comment: Added those also.

Comment: I updated my answer what I think your app routes should look like. The routes you added to your question again have empty paths, but no `pathMatch: 'false'` as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, For the default route you can just do this, instead of AppComponent

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppHolderComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Comment: app-holder is lazyloaded, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can rearrange your route definition in the `app.routing.ts` and try. Like this:

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
               { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
               { path: 'login',loadChildren: './components/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
               { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './components/password-reset/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordModule'},
               { path: 'app',loadChildren: './components/app-holder/app-holder.module#AppHolderModule' },

    ];
```

Instead of `AppComponent`, you can create a placeholder component named `HomeComponent` and use it in place of `AppComponent` in the route definition. Because, by default `AppComponent` is used as bootstrapped component in the `main.ts` file.

**Or** you can create another module called `HomeModule` and import it in the app.module.ts file and define the `path: ''` in that modules routing definition.